# How do I pay fees if I don't even land at the airport?

Tags: uk, aircraft-operations, landing-fees

So let's say I'm going from Wellesbourne (EGBW) to Coventry airport (EGBE) and at Coventry I do 1 ILS approach and go missed and return back to Wellesbourne.

Even though I never put a wheel on EGBE how will they collect the fee for doing the ILS approach? (Yeah I know... you gotta pay for an ILS approach... yuk.)

Comment: Looking at http://www.coventryairport.co.uk/downloads/fees-and-charges-2017.pdf, I see that it refers to "EC Regulation EC 785/2009". I'm fairly sure that regulation is about skimmed milk powder. :) Anyway, there are also "Circuits [and Touch and Go’s]" charges.

Comment: So if you go missed and make a second approach are you charged for two approaches?

Comment: Welcome to Europe, where stuff isn't allowed to be free.

Comment: @GdD It's not free in the US either. Joe Citizen, who has never stepped foot in a plane, pays for a PPL to shoot an approach through his taxes.

Answer (score 7):

I fly in France and I had the same question. Apparently they use the aircraft registration to identify the owner. If you rented the plane from a club or renting company, the bill is going directly to them, otherwise they are going to try contacting you. If for some reason they didn't get your registration or if the airport was uncontrolled then you don't pay the fee. That's how it works over here, however I can't say if the same would apply in the UK.

Comment: Ah right, it seems like it would be the same, thank you!