# How much does an ILS approach cost?

Tags: cost, ils

A statement in [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/37415/how-do-i-pay-fees-if-i-dont-even-land-at-the-airport), asking how to pay fees for using the airport services, without being at the airport, inspires me to ask a question.

Quote:

> (Yeah I know... you gotta pay for an ILS approach... yuk.)

- How much does it cost to do an ILS Approach (for the pilot when he pays the bill)?
- How much does it cost to do an ILS Approach for the airport (Electricity, Staff, Maintenance, Chart-making, ...)?
- Is this listed as separate item on a bill, or is it included in the airport fee?
- If it's included, how much would it be?
- What percentage is to cover maintenance cost, and what is the payment for the controllers?
- Are there differences between aircraft size?
- Are there differences between ILS Category?

I am asking this question for any country in Europe, because, as Dan Pichelmann pointed out, in the US, ILS Approaches are still free.

Comment: Which country?  In the US, it's (still) free.

Comment: @DanPichelman Any country in Europe. Whichever country someone knows of.

Comment: Keep These Mind posted a link to the [Coventry fee schedule](http://www.coventryairport.co.uk/downloads/fees-and-charges-2017.pdf) on comments on the linked question

Comment: There is zero marginal cost to an airport for an aircraft to fly an ILS approach.  There is lots of cost to install the system, some cost to maintain it, and at least a slight cost to run it (electricity).  But none of that changes if you have airplanes flying on the loc + gs all day long, or nobody in the sky at all.  So pricing & cost aren't tightly coupled here; there would be some desire to pay off the equipment and the maintenance and such for the ILS by charging those who use it, but they'd be paying some ***average*** cost, rather than any ***marginal*** costs generated.

Answer (score 2):

For New Zealand<sup>1</sup>, the [Airways Pricing Framework](https://www.airways.co.nz/assets/Uploads/Airways-Pricing-Framework.pdf) is a document which describes *how* the prices are set but not the actual prices themselves (that is in a different document that it appears you have to sign up to receive). Some excerpts:

> Consistent with international practice and ICAO guidelines, Airways uses aircraft weight as the basis for its charges.
> En-route charges also vary with distance flown. Intrinsic to the formulae is the principle that prices should be
> transparent and practicable. A simple pricing system lowers Airways’ costs and those of its customers.

For IFR approaches:

> For aircraft flying IFR, the greater of the Minimum Price or:
>
> - for aircraft weights under 5 tonnes = Base Rate x MCTOW / 5
> - for aircraft weights 5-30 tonnes = Base Rate + Weight Rate x (MCTOW – 5)
> - for aircraft weights above 30 tonnes = Base Rate + Weight Rate x 5 x Square root of (MCTOW – 5)
>
> » where the Minimum Price, Base Rate and Weight Rate are provided by the relevant price table.
> Price tables provide the prices for each service and location. Price tables are provided in Airways’
> standard terms and conditions
> » where MCTOW is an aircraft’s maximum certified take-off weight measured in tonnes.

There are also different formulas for aerodrome services, en-route domestic, and en-route oceanic service.

More information can be found at the [New Zealand Service and Pricing Framework](https://www.airways.co.nz/products-and-services/air-navigation-services/new-zealand-service-framework/) page.

<sup>1. Yes I know that New Zealand is not a country in Europe.</sup>