# Are landing fees due for an aborted landing in USA?

Tags: general-aviation, usa, landing-fees, missed-approach

Suppose I receive landing clearance for an airport that charges a landing fee, and begin my decent. Then, for some reason I have to abort the landing and instead of going around and landing there I change my plans and wish to depart the airspace. Will I be liable for any landing fees if my wheels haven’t touched the runway at such airport?

I am asking for GA in the USA.

Comment: Related: [How do I pay fees if I don't even land at the airport?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/37415)

Answer (score 5):

I commuted to work in my plane into an airport with a landing fee for a few years (I was doing it frequently enough that I paid for an annual subscription with unlimited landings). In Canada you won't be charged if you go around and I can't imagine being charged in the US either.  Although ATC records the landing, the fee is usually levied by the airport authority and is intended to cover airport services, not ATC services.